# Is there anyway to have hangouts outside google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Is there any way by which we can have a hangout session within our webapp, say in an iframe   ? 
I was about to experiment with hangout api, but going by existing apps on hangout,  it seems they can only be viewed and used from within Google+.

Is there a work around where I can make the user feel that hangout is a part of my app rather than my app being part of the hangout ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way to embed a hangout into your web application, but you can use the [hangout button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) to launch a hangout app. This allows you to integrate features and data from your web application into a hangout.

The hangout button is made up of an image and a hangout launching link. It comes in a [few sizes](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#button). Here's the code for the smallest size (75x19 px)

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=APP_ID" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/hangout/1/gplus-hangout-15x79-normal.png"
    alt="Start a Hangout"
    style="border:0;width:79px;height:15px;"/>
</a>
```

In this snippet you must substitute `APP_ID` with your application's ID from the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). When you are viewing your project you'll find the application ID at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there's no way of embedding a Hangout app in your web application. But, there's an [opened issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=28) where you can add your comments about the need of this feature and Google might release it in their future API releases.