# Any way to incoroprate Google Hangouts in a web app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-hangouts

I would like to embed a Hangout into my web application. 
The application supports login via OAuth 2.0, but looking at the Hangout API it seems you can only develop apps within their container - Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check the following two questions, as they seem to be asking what you are asking.  If not, can you clarify your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140168/embedding-google-hangout-app-in-web-application

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189926/is-there-anyway-to-have-hangouts-outside-google/10199047#10199047

Answer (score 0):

Think more of embedding your web app within their container (speaking from personal experience).

That container is, to put it mildly, byzantine.